# ImageViews set programmatically do not appear android

Tags: android, imageview

I have a integer array in the res/values/strings.xml like this :

```
<integer-array name="test">

    <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>

</integer-array>
```

I want to create programmatically a set of imagebuttons,but when I use setImageResource(forimageview[i]) function Images cannot be seen.

my MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int [] forimageview ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addchild();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private void addchild(){
    Resources res = getResources();
    forimageview = res.getIntArray(R.array.test);
    LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < forimageview.length ; ++i){

        ImageButton imagebutton = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
        imagebutton.setId(i+1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imagebutton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        imagebutton.setImageResource(forimageview[i]);
        imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        linearlayout.addView(imagebutton, imageparams);

    }       



}

}
```

Result :

[image]

edited:

my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide your layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you defined the `array` is not the correct. Firstly, you're defining it in `strings.xml`, it has to be in `arrays.xml`.

Secondly, it's not a `int` array, but `string` array, so it has to be something like this:

```
<string-array name="your_imgs">
    <item>@drawable/first</item>
    <item>@drawable/second</item>
    <item>@drawable/third</item>
</string-array>
```

To access them, just use something like this:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.your_imgs);

for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++)
  myView.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
```

More on TypedArray in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray).

Comment: What is the 35th line of your MainActivity.java file?

Comment: sorry, solved. but how can I get array size with imgs object?